# How do I sort the symbols of other sections besides the "COMMON" section?

Tags: c, gcc, build, linker, static-linking

The gnu linker "ld" supplies the option "-sort-common" which sorts the uninitialized global parameters, known as the COMMON section symbols, by their size. When the linker aligns the symbols to even addresses, this option helps minimizing the holes in the section.
For example, if we define:

> --main.c
>
> char a;
>
> short b;
>
> char c;
>
> int main() { return 0; }

and compile it to main.o without "sort-common" we will get a "hole" of one byte between the address of "a" and the address of "b". If we use "sort-common" the linker will reorder the parameters to "a, c, b", and since a's size is 1 byte and c's size is 1 byte, there will be no "hole" between their adresses.
My problem is that my code looks like:

> --main.c
>
> char a = 0;
>
> short b = 0;
>
> char c = 0;
>
> ...

In this case a, b, and c are in the BSS section, which means that "sort-common" will not affect them.

**How do I sort the symbols of other sections besides the "COMMON" section?**

I also searched many options in the LD scripts, unsuccessfully.

**Update**: I read something about "Order" value in the segment_flags, and didn't understand how to use it. Any help is appreciable.

Comment: afaik even your uninitialized variables will end up in the BSS section; from the ld manual: 'This option tells ld to sort the common symbols by alignment [...] when it places them in the appropriate output sections'; in C, data with static storage duration is always initialized

Comment: by default they will end up in the BSS, unless you set a different section in the ld-script (using "*(COMMON)"). But I want to sort the non-common BSS section, and the Data section as well.
Can I use map-files for that? I read something about "Order" value in the segment_flags, and didn't understand how to use it.